# Matplotlib bar chart different colors for each bar

Tags: matplotlib, colors

I am trying to create a simple horizontal bar chart but I want to spruce it up with each bar using a teams color. I thought it would be as simple as passing each teams hex color to the color parameter as an array but what I get is each bar displaying as the first color provided in the array.

```
data.plot(kind="barh", color=['#A71930', '#DF4601', '#AB0003', '#003278', '#FF5910', '#0E3386', '#BA0021', '#E81828', '#473729', '#D31145', '#0C2340', '#005A9C', '#BD3039', '#EB6E1F', '#C41E3A', '#33006F', '#C6011F', '#004687', '#CE1141', '#134A8E', '#27251F', '#FDB827', '#0C2340', '#FD5A1E', '#00A3E0', '#ffc52f', '#003831', '#005C5C', '#E31937', '#8FBCE6'])
plt.title('Team Ranking Marginal Doller Spent per Marginal Win')
plt.ylabel('Team')
plt.xlabel('Marginal Doller Spent per Marginal Win')
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')
plt.gcf().set_size_inches(10, 12)
plt.show()
```

Here is the result
[image]

Comment: You are using pandas' plotting. The colors are for each of the columns in the dataframe, apparently there is only one column. (You seem to have forgotten to [add](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/71577374/edit) test data to the post.)  You could try seaborn's barplot instead: `sns.barplot(x=data.iloc[:,0], y=data.index, palette=['#A71930', '#DF4601', ...')` (this example uses `.iloc` as test data is missing).

Comment: Also, instead of plotting the complete dataframe, you could just plot one column. In that case, the colors will be used for the individual bars. `data.iloc[:,0].plot(kind="barh", color=['#A71930', '#DF4601', '#AB0003', '#003278', ...])` (or `data[' column name'].plot(...)` if you know the column name.)

Comment: When creating a visualization, it should not be "spruced up", unless it helps convey information. If the colors of the bars do not convey information, then the plot bars should be a single color, otherwise you're just adding clutter, and obfuscating the message of the visualization.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you are using pandas to plot, which returns an axis object. You can modify the color of each bar by iterating through the patches:

```
colors=['#A71930', '#DF4601', '#AB0003', '#003278', '#FF5910', '#0E3386', '#BA0021', '#E81828', '#473729', '#D31145', '#0C2340', '#005A9C', '#BD3039', '#EB6E1F', '#C41E3A', '#33006F', '#C6011F', '#004687', '#CE1141', '#134A8E', '#27251F', '#FDB827', '#0C2340', '#FD5A1E', '#00A3E0', '#ffc52f', '#003831', '#005C5C', '#E31937', '#8FBCE6']
ax=data.plot(kind='barh')
for patch,color in zip(ax.patches,colors):
    patch.set_facecolor(color)
```

It's a bit of a work around, but its nice to get to know how to access the pandas generated figures in case the built-in functions leave something to be desired.

(Edited a variable name because someone in the comments said it was ugly)

Comment: Pandas `.plot` returns an `ax`, not a figure. (`ax.axes` and `ax` would be the same subplot object). Note that `data[...column name....].plot(kind='barh', colors=...)` seems a bit simpler.

Comment: True pandas returns an axes.subplot, but the patches are still accessed the same way. I tested my code and it works. I tested `data[...column name....].plot(kind='barh', colors=...)` and it returned `'Rectangle' object has no property 'colors'`

Comment: Your code works, but calling the return value `fig` is a bad idea. Note that if it were a `figure`, you would need `fig.axes[0].patches` to get access to the bars.  The correct way to access the bars would be `ax = data.plot(...)` and `ax.patches`. (Now you are using `ax.axes.patches` which only works because `ax` and `ax.axes` are the same subplot.)  I made a small mistake in when calling `.plot` on a column (instead of on the dataframe), it should be `data[...column name....].plot(kind='barh', color=...)`, with `color` instead of `colors`.

Comment: As i said before you are correct about the returned object. However your suggestion still does not work as it sets all bars to the first color in the list.

Comment: When working with a `series` (so a column of a dataframe, not to be confused with a dataframe with only one column), [`color=`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.plot.bar.html) can have a separate color for each of the bars.  But, please, edit your answer and replace that ugly `fig = data.plot(...)` with `ax = ...`.